# Terminating adb.exe?

Tags: adb

I am trying to hot spot my htc evo.  When I click on PDAnet,  it tells me that I have to terminate adb.exe.  how do i terminate adb.exe.   thank

Comment: ctrl+alt+del, look for adb and then terminate process. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

`adb kill-server`

You need to run that from wherever you installed the android tools.

Comment: This is the preferred way rather than killing it from the task manager. There's not a lot of shut-down logic, but it's always better to do things in a calm manner if you can. Just create a .bat file to do this and stick it some place convenient.